# Do the C++ operators new and new[] throw std::bad_alloc on Android?

Tags: android, c++, exception, android-ndk, new-operator

Will any exception be thrown when an attempt to allocate memory fails?

I just recently learned that exceptions are supported in Android.

Comment: Why did you add the jni tag? My question is not about jni.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I downloaded the ndk and found this in the docs folder, CPLUSPLUS-SUPPORT.HTML .

> ### I. C++ Exceptions support:
>
> The NDK toolchain supports C++ exceptions, since NDK r5, however all C++
>   sources are compiled with -fno-exceptions support by default, for
>   compatibility reasons with previous releases.
>
> To enable it, use the '-fexceptions' C++ compiler flag. This can be done
>   by adding the following to every module definition in your Android.mk:
>
> ```
> LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += -fexceptions
> ```
>
> More simply, add a single line to your Application.mk, the setting will
>   automatically apply to all your project's NDK modules:
>
> ```
> APP_CPPFLAGS += -fexceptions
> ```
>
> NOTE: The obsolete "arm-eabi-4.4.0" toolchain provided for backwards
>         compatibility with this NDK does not support exceptions!

So exceptions seems to be supported, as long as the application is compiled with '-fexceptions'. So my understanding is that code compiled with -fexceptions will throw std::bad_alloc on failure to allocate memory.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't think exceptions were supported on Android. If this has been changed recently could you post the link to your reference article? I was under the impression a failed allocation with new operator will return a null pointer on Android.

In which case if you use `(nothrow)` on your end you should comply with their default allocation behavior and get the same result as expected on Android.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/new/nothrow/

Comment: I actually can't remember, but I found this when searching:
http://www.crystax.net/android/ndk-r5.php

Comment: Ah that seems like a homegrown implementation of the google NDK and the google NDK is compiled with no exceptions by default. You'd have to recompile the whole NDK with `-fexceptions` to enable them. However I would be very wary about how well it supports STL and standard C++ exceptions. I'd still recommend avoiding the whole mess by using `(nothrow)` as Android wasn't really designed with exceptions in mind.

Comment: Ok, I downloaded the ndk and found documentation on the matter. Unfortunately not allowed to answer my own question, but as I understand it exceptions are supported for code compiled with -fexceptions , without having to recompile the entire ndk. But the STL implementation is compiled with -fnoexceptions. This is all good news for me, since I have existing code that I wish to port to Android.

Comment: FYI you can answer your own question ... self learning and sharing of what you found is supported around here. Sometimes the best answer is the one you figure out for yourself after all.